# Qt5 функция iscontain не работает

Tags: c++, qt5

Есть программа Qt5, 2 кнопки: одна записывает данные в файл (имя, фамилия, номер телефона, 0), а вторая ищет данного человека по номеру телефона и меняет цифру 0 на другое значение, как сделал чтобы меняло цифру 0, iscontain перестал работать, всегда пишет, что номер телефона не найден
вот код:

```
//если isempty ложь, делаем функцию программы. Если нет - ничего
   if(isempty == false)
   {
       while(!f.atEnd())
       {
           str = f.readLine();//считываем строку
           if(str.contains(phonenumber))//если строка содержит номер телефона, вытаскиваем сумму
           {
               name = str.section(" ", 0, 0);
               lastname = str.section(" ", 1, 1);
               phonenumber1 = str.section(" ", 2, 2);
               sumfromfile = str.section(" ", 3, 3);//вытаскиваем сумму из файла
               iscontain = true;//
               break;

           }
       }

       if(iscontain == false)
       {
           QMessageBox::warning(this, "Ошибка", "Номер телефона не найден");
       }
       else
       {
           sumtodouble = sumfromfile.toDouble();
           sumtodouble = sumtodouble-(sumtodouble*5/100); //Подсчитываем скидку
           //Делаем переменную suminmsgbox для вывода
           sumasstring = QString::number(sumtodouble);
           suminmsgbox.append("Итого ");
           suminmsgbox.append(sumasstring);
           suminmsgbox.append(" грн");
           QMessageBox::information(this, "Итого", suminmsgbox);
           f.close();
           f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
           while(!f.atEnd())
           {
               str = f.readLine();//считываем строку
               if(str.contains(phonenumber))//если строка содержит номер телефона, вытаскиваем сумму
               {
                   QTextStream out(&f);
                   out<<name<<" "<<lastname<<" "<<phonenumber<<" "<<sumtodouble<<"\n";
                   break;

               }
           }
       }
```

цифра 0 должна стать значением sumtodouble, sumasstring делал для QMessageBox. Код из функции кнопки, которая ищет человека. С добавлением человека проблем нет

Comment: Что находится в `str` после `readline()`? p.s. Напишите просто `if (!iscontain)`

Comment: Я решил не заниматься фигней с файлами, пробую через БД, так проще, спасибо за ответ)